# How create a Redis ElastiCache cluster using AWS-CLI from snapshots in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redis, aws-cli, amazon-elasticache

What I'm trying to do is to use aws-cli to create an ElastiCache cluster based on my ElastiCache snapshots in S3, and my ElastiCache is cluster-enabled mode.

I followed this [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Clusters.Create.CLI.html) to create a cluster-enabled Redis cache and here's my command:

`aws elasticache create-cache-cluster --cache-cluster-id stevescachecluster1 --cache-node-type cache.m4.large --engine redis --engine-version 3.2.4 --cache-parameter-group default.redis3.2.cluster.on --num-cache-nodes 1 --snapshot-arns arn:aws:s3:::MY_S3_BUCKET-elasticache/stevesun-elasticache-0002.rdb --cache-subnet-group-name my-cache-dev`

The above command fails due to 

`An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the CreateCacheCluster operation: Cluster mode should be disabled in parameter group, but found it is enabled.`

This is what confuses me, the above linked tutorial explicitly said that if yo want a cluster-mode enabled cache, please use ***.cluster.on*** option in your arguments.

Then I looked more into this aws-cli command [reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticache/create-cache-cluster.html): for this parameter: `--cache-parameter-group-name`, its documentation says: `You cannot use any parameter group which has cluster-enabled='yes' when creating a cluster.`

Isn't this contradictionary from this cli reference documentation to that cli tutorial?

Please correct me where I understand it wrong.
And also, how can I create a cluster-mode enabled cache from S3 snapshots?

Thanks.

I checked and found that 3.2.4 is the latest [version](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/SelectEngine.RedisVersions.html#SelectEngine.RedisVersions.3-2-4) that AWS ElatiCache has right now.

Edit 1:

Then I just created a single-node cache using this command:
`aws elasticache create-cache-cluster --cache-cluster-id stevescachecluster1 --cache-node-type cache.m4.large --engine redis --engine-version 3.2.4 --cache-parameter-group default.redis3.2 --num-cache-nodes 1 --snapshot-arns arn:aws:s3:::MY_S3_BUCKET-elasticache/stevesun-elasticache-0002.rdb --cache-subnet-group-name my-cache-dev`.

Then I went to the console and selected my newly launched single-node cache and clicked `Modify`, I tried to change it to cluster.on, but got this exception:
`The parameter cluster-enabled has a different value in the requested parameter group than the current parameter group. This parameter value cannot be changed for a cache cluster.`

So, my attempt to launch a single-node cache first and then change it to be a cluster mode also failed.

Edit 2:

Then I thought it's that I needed to allocate more than 1 node for a cluster-enabled mode, so I changed this parameter `--num-cache-nodes` to `2`, but I got this exception:

`An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CreateCacheCluster operation: Cannot create a Redis cluster with a NumCacheNodes parameter greater than 1.`

This is even more confusing to me, a cluster definitely needs more than 1 node, then why does it not allow greater than 1??

Although its [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticache/create-cache-cluster.html) says `For clusters running Redis, this value must be 1.`. Why is this requirement? Then how can we create a new redis cluster from snapshots?
Help please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a Redis (cluster mode enabled) Cluster (AWS CLI)

Redis (cluster mode enabled) clusters (API/CLI: replication groups) cannot be created using the create-cache-cluster operation. To create a Redis (cluster mode enabled) cluster (API/CLI: replication group), see Creating a Redis (cluster mode enabled) Replication Group from Scratch (AWS CLI).

Per AWS [Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Clusters.Create.CLI.html).

Looks like [`Replication Group from Scratch`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Replication.CreatingReplGroup.NoExistingCluster.Cluster.html#Replication.CreatingReplGroup.NoExistingCluster.Cluster.CLI) is the way to go. I'll try it now.

Comment: could you share your solution here?

Comment: sorry I don't recall exactly, but [Replication Group from Scratch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Replication.CreatingReplGroup.NoExistingCluster.Cluster.html#Replication.CreatingReplGroup.NoExistingCluster.Cluster.CLI) was the way to go and helped me out.

Comment: See also [replication for cluster mode disabled from scratch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Replication.CreatingReplGroup.NoExistingCluster.Classic.html#Replication.CreatingReplGroup.NoExistingCluster.Classic.CLI)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/APIReference/API_CreateCacheCluster.html), cache clusters with size > 1 are not supported when for redis.

Also, for redis, if you want to restore from a snapshot you have to use the `--snapshot-name` parameter to specify the snapshot not the `--snapshot-arns` parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Then what's the proper way to restore a redid cluster from snapshots? Not a single node Redis.